# Images for multiple select values

Tags: attributes, multiple, select

I am using the following to display image icons to represent the operating systems of a device.

```
<?php if($_product->getoperating_system()): ?><li><?php $os=$_product->getAttributeText('operating_system');
$osid=$_product->getoperating_system();
echo '<a href="/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?operating_system%5B%5D='.str_replace(' ', '_',$osid).'"><img class="specicon" src="/media/avenueimages/icons/'.str_replace(' ', '_',$os).'.png" alt="'.$os.'" title="'.$os.'"></a><p>'.$os.'</p>' ;?></li><?php endif; ?>
```

Results are as shown here:
[image]

I would like to do the same with a **multiple select** attribute.

This code displays the attribute value ids:

```
<?php echo $_product->getData('printer_functions'); ?>
```

How do I modify the first code to display an icon for each selected value?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that has worked for me.
I have modified code i found online:

```
<?php if($_product->getprinter_functions()): ?>
<?php $sportTypes = explode(",",$_product->getResource()
->getAttribute('printer_functions')->getFrontend()
->getValue($_product));

foreach($sportTypes as $key => $value){
        echo '<li><img class="specicon" src="/media/avenueimages/icons/'.str_replace(' ', '_',$value).'.png" alt="'.$value.'" title="'.$value.'"></a><p>'.$value.'</p></li>';
    }
?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Here are the results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For multiple select attributes you can get the selected values like this:

```
$ids = $_product->getPrinterFunctions();
```

This returns an array or a string with the values concatenated by comma depending on the value for the flat catalog products flag.
So do this next.

```
if (!is_array($ids)) {
    $ids = explode(',', $ids);
}
```

Now you can loop through the `$ids` and do something with each id.
You can get the labels of the options like this

```
$texts = $_product->getAttributeText('printer_functions');
```

This will get you a string with the labels separated by comma.
So you can make that an array like this:

```
$texts = explode(',', $texts);
```

If everything is OK then `$ids` and `$texts` arrays should have the same count.

And small tip:
Don't use `echo '<a href="/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?operating_system%5B%5D='.str_replace(' ', '_',$osid).'">`
It will not work if your magento instance is located in one folder.
Use this instead:

```
 $url = Mage::getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result', array('_query'=> 'operating_system[]='.str_replace(' ', '_',$osid)));

 echo '<a href="'.$url.'"'>...'
```